# Best lessons from well built web sites

Tags: scalability

I am looking for examples of web sites that developers can learn from, inspiring sites that get everything right.

In particular, a site should excel in all these areas:

- Consistently fast load speed
- Semantic HTML
- Accessible
- RESTful
- Gracefully degrades
- Appropriate HTTP headers, including caching
- Secure

Please nominate a site and explain why it wins, and what we should learn from it.

Comment: Please repost this question on Programmers.SE and make it more "constructive" the concepts behind it are very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and Google recommendations for making your web site as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest http://html5boilerplate.com as a great example of didactic web development. It's entire raison d'être is to exemplify a the best practices it promotes.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like they put a lot of thought into that boilerplate.